# Blushifted receding objects in an accelerating expanding universe?

Tags: electromagnetism, cosmology, space-expansion, redshift

I found this article (https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0104349) which apparently shows that there can be blue-shifted objects in an expanding universe.

However, it is not clear to me whether this would apply to an accelerating expanding universe (like our own one)? And if it can be applied, would the object keep blue-shifting all the way and constantly upon disappearing from our horizon?

Answer (score 0):

There are blueshifted objects in our universe, such as the Andromeda galaxy.

The paper talks about "receding blueshifted objects", but this is simply because the relative velocity of objects in a curved spacetime is not well defined. Very distant objects are unambiguously receding from us, and Andromeda is unambiguously approaching us, but there are borderline cases where different measures of relative speed may give results that differ in sign. All the speed measures in that case will be close to zero (which is why the "noise" of the differences between them can change the sign). So there can be an object that appears slightly blueshifted while it recedes slowly by another (somewhat arbitrary) metric, but there can't be an object that remains blueshifted as it heads toward the cosmological horizon.

Comment: So, even if there is a blue shifted receding object in our universe, it would eventually redshift (instead of keeping the blueshift until reaching the cosmological horizon)? @benrg

Comment: @vengaq A blueshifted "receding" object is basically at rest relative to us, not heading toward the horizon. But the ultimate fate of everything is to fall through the horizon. Whenever that happens, it will redshift increasingly (to infinity) as it falls.